# Disable picture-in-picture for embedded videos in Safari 11

Tags: safari, html5-video, vimeo-player

I have an embedded video from Vimeo in a web page. In Safari on MacOS, the video player shows a picture-in-picture button, which I'd like to know if it's possible to disable.

On Chrome and Firefox on MacOS the button does not show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide only Picture in Picture (PiP) control from safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042785/how-to-hide-only-picture-in-picture-pip-control-from-safari)