# How to hide only Picture in Picture (PiP) control from safari

Tags: javascript, html, macos, css, safari

I need to hide only one video control from safari browser which is Picture in Picture (PiP). Is there is any solution for that ?

Can we hide this using HTML5?

[image]

Comment: http://dailymactips.com/how-to-turn-off-picture-in-picture-in-ios/

Comment: and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430331/safari-picture-in-picture-custom-html5-video-controller) suggests you have to *enable* it, i.e. default is not enabled - perhaps something in that question will help

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for your quick reply. I already tried this approach but its not working.

Comment: I have to do it in html5 video player via script

Comment: yeah well, as there are literally hundreds of results when searching, and the two I mentioned you claim to have already tried, you'll just have to wait for someone who actually knows :p

Comment: I didn't find a way to hide the icon, but you can *block* the feature with `vid.onwebkitpresentationmodechanged = e => {if(vid.webkitPresentationMode === 'picture-in-picture') vid.webkitSetPresentationMode('inline');}`.

Answer (score 7):

**disablePictureInPicture** attribute can be used for that now

```
<video disablepictureinpicture controlslist="nodownload"></video>
```

details here:
https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/#disable-pip

Comment: Works with Chrome but not Safari.

Comment: disablepictureinpicture is still not working in Safari 16.6 (18615.3.12.11.2)

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be any official way to do it...

Currently in Safari it's all or nothing (with `controls=false`).

---

The [shadow-targetting pseudo elements selectors](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3759334) doesn't seem to work on this browser, unlike on Blink browsers, and even though I found references of an `::-webkit-media-controls-picture-in-picture-button` on the Internet.

---

So for today, the only solution is to disable all the default controls of your video element and to build you own controls.
If you wish, you can make it conditional though:

```
if(typeof vidElem.webkitSupportsPresentationMode === 'function' &&
  vidElem.webkitSupportsPresentationMode('picture-in-picture') ) {
    vidElem.controls = false;
    buildCustomControls(vidElem);
}
```

---

For the future, there might a [`controlsList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/controlsList) attribute, which [drafts specs](https://wicg.github.io/controls-list/html-output/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-media-controlslist) currently only handles `nodownload`, `nofullscreen` and `noremoteplayback`, but I can't see why a `nopicture-in-picture` couldn't make its way there, if this attribute (mainly motivated by Blink browsers, once again) ever gets out of the drafts.

Comment: "@Kaiido thanks for your suggestion. I will talk to my client regarding custom controls, it seems this is only the solution.